# phpmyadmin just will not work fully

Tags: password, mysql, phpmyadmin

Right, I've spent upwards of 8 hours on this and I just can't solve it!

Firstly, I couldn't log in to phpmyadmin with every combination of possible default password and usernames until I had to go into config.inc.php and change a setting (I think autopassword?) to "False". Then I logged in and nothing worked properly, so I had to import a file, so I did and it kind of worked, but when I went to access my tables after it gave an error and refused to work.  So I tried reinstalling phpmyadmin in various ways, but now I can't log in at all, no combination of username and password or no password will work!

I've tried that many different things I can't even remember what did what now, and I'm pretty sure I need to remove the entire thing and start fresh but it doesn't seem to work since when it creates the login in the new install, the details I entered (or ven didn't enter) do not work.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

(Also, no matter what order of things I do the settings prompt will always give me an error, various different kinds.)

EDIT:

When I get close to what might seem like a solution I will always get this message:

```
sambo@sambo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[2] 10387
sambo@sambo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:~$ 131112 17:25:57 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
```

Comment: Is the username and password you are trying the same as your mysql username and pass?

Comment: I don't know anymore, I've tried that many username and password combos and reconfigures I don't know which is the definite username and password anymore, but ANYTHING I do now will not get past
`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`
No matter what I try.

Comment: Try to purge everything related to this (something like `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge phpmyadmin mysql-server mysql-client apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql`, then check if everything was really removed). Then start over and install the packages `mysql-server` and `phpmyadmin` (that should install everything that is needed, and you should be asked to input a password for the first mysql user several times). Tried this now in Ubuntu 13.10 using Synaptic and I didn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to, and nothing was already working, just try re installing everything including Apache2, MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin using the commands

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2 phpmyadmin mysql
```

Then, just reinstall it (making sure to update things really quick before you do so)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2 phpmyadmin mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

If phpmyadmin fails, you could give Adminer a try. Everything is included in one php file and the installation is a lot easier. But you have all the necessary features and a nice interface.

http://www.adminer.org/